# Snow Leopard Tiles Overflow Finder window

Tags: snow-leopard, mac, finder

I have somewhat recently noticed that when I have have the Finder mode set to Tiles, that the tiles are too wide for the window. For example, it shows 7 across (in a row), whereas that makes it to where I have to scroll sideways in order to see all the documents. It, in effect makes it very difficult to use the Finder tile display. Is there a way I can fix this?

I can increase the Finder window, and it works then, but most often I don't want a massive window. I can also shrink the size of the tiles, but that starts to defeat the purpose of using the tiles.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. This isn't something I can't live with, but it would be **really** nice to get fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Keep Arranged By setting:

[image: Keep Arranged By]

Comment: That's great! Thanks. I wondered if it was something obvious that I had missed.